# PHP mb_strlen with string append chr(241)

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, strlen

So I ran into this issue and I've simplified it as much as possible.

```
$test = 'XXX' . chr(241) . 'XXX';
print($test); // XXX�XXX
print(mb_strlen($test, 'UTF-8')); // 4
print(count(str_split($test))); // 7
```

So basically my question is: why is chr(241) not returning one single character making the length of the string 7?  It's six characters, I add one, and it's four characters?  Why is chr(241) not equal to html entity 241?

Other information listed below.  Note that as long as you don't add X AFTER the chr(241), everybody is happy:

```
print(mb_detect_encoding($test)); // UTF-8
print(mb_strlen('XX' . chr(241) . 'XX', 'UTF-8')); // 3
print(mb_strlen('X' . chr(241) . 'X', 'UTF-8')); // 2
print(mb_strlen('' . chr(241) . 'X', 'UTF-8')); // 1
print(mb_strlen('X' . chr(241) . '', 'UTF-8')); // 2
print(mb_strlen('XXX' . chr(241) . '', 'UTF-8')); // 4
print(mb_strlen(chr(241), 'UTF-8')); // 1
```

It seems like an encoding issue but how?  The file is saved as UTF-8, the internal encoding is UTF-8, and I'm not passing data anywhere to mess it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **UTF-8** all ASCII characters under `127` are represented by one byte (binary representation of `0xxxxxxx`) and **code points** larger than `127` are represented by **multi-byte** sequences.
Multi-byte sequences are composed of a **leading byte** and one or more **continuation bytes**.

The leading byte's **high order** bits serve to tell us how many continuation bytes to use and for that purpose it has two or more high-order 1s followed by a 0, i.e. the high bits can be `110` or `1110` or `11110` or `111110`. The number of the high-order bits are equal to the sum of the leading byte plus the continuation bytes, i.e.

```
110   means 1 leading byte + 1 continuation byte 
1110  means 1 leading byte + 2 continuation bytes
11110 means 1 leading byte + 3 continuation bytes
```

Continuation bytes which follow a leading byte have the format `10xxxxxx`.

Applying the above to your `$test` string:

We have three bytes `ord('X')` that all are **ascii** chars under `127`, so those are counted as 1 char to 1 byte,

Then we have a `chr(241)` with binary representation of 11110001 so it's a **leading byte** since it has two or more high-bits.

Since it has 4 high bits that means that the code point it represents consists of 1 **leading byte** plus 3 **continuation bytes**, so the 3 `ord('X')` bytes that remain in the string are considered by `mb_strlen()` as continuation bytes* and although together with the chr(241) are a total of four bytes they are counted as one UTF-8 code point.

*Here we must state that those trailing 'X's are not valid continuation bytes since they do not conform to the standard of a continuation byte. However `mb_strlen()` will consume as explained above up to 3 more bytes after the `chr(241)`. You can test this if you add another `'X`' or you subtract `'X's` from the end of the `$test` string.

**UPDATE: Verifying the findings:**

```
/*
 * The following strings are non valid UTF-8 encodings.
 * We test to see if mb_strlen() consumes non VALID UTF-8
 * byte strings like they are valid (driven by the leading bytes)
 *
 */

/*
 * 0xc0 as a leading byte should consume one continuation byte
 * so the length reported should be 6
 */ 
$test = 'XXX' . chr(0xc0) . 'XXX'; 
echo '6 == ', mb_strlen($test, 'UTF8');

/*
 * 0xe0 as a leading byte should consume two continuation bytes
 * so the length reported should be 5
 */ 
$test = 'XXX' . chr(0xe0) . 'XXX'; 
echo '5 == ', mb_strlen($test, 'UTF8'), PHP_EOL;

// results in 6 == 6 and 5 == 5
```

**UPDATE 2**:

An example of constructing with `chr()` the same symbol in Latin-1 and UTF-8.

```
$euroSignAscii = chr(0x80); // Latin-1 extended ASCII
$euroSignUtf8 = chr(0xe2) . chr(0x82) . chr(0xac); // UTF-8
```

Take note if you echo the above strings the encoding of your console or web page (if it is latin-1 then the `$euroSignAscii` will output correctly, if it is UTF-8 then the `$euroSignUtf8` will output correctly).

---

**Links:**

A good reference is the relevant [UTF-8 article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

A classic post from Joel Spolsky [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

And to get the feel [UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

Comment: I'm not sure if the explanation is that complex, or simply "it's invalid UTF-8". Either way, nice explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Of course the "it's invalid UTF-8" is a valid answer and maybe the correct short one. However its not the one that explains the observed facts and hence the one with the most educational value. From the answer you can deduce a) that if the character added wasn't chr(241) but chr(195) then the reported length would be 6 instead of 4 and b) that mb_strlen() will parse incorrect UTF-8 as correct considering only the leading bytes for guidance (I will have to check with the implementation to be 100% sure for that one).

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I assume if my file was encoded in ASCII, it would have given me the expected answer (since my fix was to do mb_strlen($test, 'ASCII')).  


But what part of the code is wrong?  Is it the chr() function?  The documentation says _Returns a one-character string containing the character specified by ascii._  It seems like the word "character" isn't accurate.

Comment: @Andrew Indeed, the word "character" is an oversimplification which breaks down under certain circumstances. `chr` returns a *byte*. More specifically, it simply returns the binary value of the decimal number you put in. That's why the maximum accepted input to `chr` is 255. What you're creating is a binary string, you could do the same with `"XXX\xF1XXX"` for the same effect. How many *characters* that is depends on which encoding you interpret this binary in; since it's invalid UTF-8 you get bad results. See http://kunststube.net/encoding for more background details.

Comment: @ilalopoulos I just meant that I'm not sure whether `mb_strlen` simply fails because it hiccups on a broken encoding and simply stops after 4 characters, or whether it actually counts in the way you describe. I haven't done any experiments on this, I was just throwing this thought in  off the top of my head.

Comment: @deceje since I wasn't 100% sure either, I made some simple tests for the findings which show that `mb_strlen` will treat even non valid utf-8 like valid ones. I have updated my answer with those tests.

Comment: @andrew since you add one byte > 127 inside that byte string the results will be different when you ask PHP to treat it like it is UTF-8 (valid or not valid) from what you get when you treat it like ASCII. I have added some links to the answer. That of Joel on encodings maybe will help to clarify things further.

Comment: Given that, does chr() called on values > 127 have any real use?

Comment: Why chr() wouldn't have any real use? chr() is for character/byte manipulation (here character means one byte). I have added a simple example of using chr() to construct the same symbol in Latin-1 extended ASCII and UTF-8.